# Any Reason to have all class names in css file / JQuery best practices

Tags: jquery, css, razor

I'm new to JQuery and am in the process of writing a bunch of selectors that do things like turn on and off conference sessions in a sessions list.  For example, I have three types of sessions and I have associated a class name with those three types.  My html generated looks kind of like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="technicalClass sessionTitle">my tech class1</li>
  <li class="technicalClass sessionTitle">my tech class2</li>
  <li class="businessClass sessionTitle"> my bus class1</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any reason I need to actually put technicalClass and businessClass in my real CSS file?  I'm not planning on doing anything but selecting on it.

Thanks

Comment: CSS is for styling, if you don't want to give them colors and such, don't put them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CSS class for JQuery markers all of the time in my apps without defining them in the CSS file.  No problem at all doing that; it's a pretty common way of achieving certain tasks with JQuery.  HTML and CSS is very flexible that way; they are not like JavaScript which raises an error if the member isn't defined.

Comment: Just to add to this a little bit, the class is defined for you in the DOM object, which is where jQuery will go to find the object.  This is perfectly fine and reusable, where as ids are not reusable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question right, you're asking about classes you adds to the DOM for javascript-jQuery manipulation.

No, you don't need to add them to the CSS file, there is no benefit from doing it.

R# for some reason marks the classes you add to the DOM if they don't have a definition in a CSS file, it can be helpful and annoying, you can turn it off if it bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

You dont really need all that classes. You can do:

```
<ul id="sessionTitle">
  <li class="technicalClass">my tech class1</li>
  <li class="technicalClass">my tech class2</li>
  <li class="businessClass"> my bus class1</li>
</ul>
```

or even better:

```
<ul id="sessionTitle">
  <li>my tech class1</li>
  <li>my tech class2</li>
  <li>my bus class1</li>
</ul>
```

And access it via jQuery with

```
$('#sessionTitle li')
```

Comment: thanks for this. I was really thinking about primarily the filtering problem which seems OK based on others comments.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no mean to select tech classes or business classes individually, then you should only select them on the .sessionTitle attribute.